# SQL inner join and where performance comparison

Tags: sql

If we have 2 tables, `tableA` (with `column1, column2`) and `tableB` (with `column1, column2`), what's the difference between the following two queries? Which one has better performance? What if we have indexing for both tables?

**Query #1:**

```
select
    b.column2
from
    tableA a,
    tableB b
where
    a.column1 = b.column1
    and a.column2 = ?;
```

**Query #2:**

```
select
    b.column2
from
    tableA a
inner join 
    tableB b on a.column1 = b.column1
where
    a.column2 = ?;
```

Comment: actually they will perform equally from older ANSI where clause to make equality join as to EXPLICIT and proper join, internal to the sql engine will be the same. They are JOINED on the same "column1" ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will perform equally. One is an ansi style and the other is old fashioned style of joining
You may compare the explain plans and most likely you will find them to be the same.

Comment: I execute the explain plans on MySQL. They are the same.

Answer (score 2):

2nd query has better performance.

1. You are using cross join in your first query and then filtering the results. Imagine having 10000 records in both the tables, it will produce 10000*10000 combinations.

Comment: actually they will perform equally from older ANSI to proper join, internal to the sql engine will be the same.  They are JOINED on the same "column1" ID.  The only Cartesian result will be if either side table has more than one value for the same ID such as parent child, but not EVERY record to EVERY record.  Also, what if Table A has IDs 1-1000, and table B has IDs 3000-4000, it would return NO records.